# Checking for a C++ compiler's presence

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, gnu, autotools, autoconf

The GNU documentation for `AC_PROG_CXX` states that:

> Otherwise, if the macro is invoked without an argument, then search
>   for a C++ compiler under the likely names (first g++ and c++ then
>   other names). If none of those checks succeed, then as a last resort
>   set CXX to g++.

which implies that whether or not a working C++ compiler is found, the `CXX` variable will be set to something. As a result, it is impossible to use `CXX` to know whether a C++ compiler is available.

How can I check that a C++ compiler is available at `./configure` time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra [`AC_CHECK_PROG`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Generic-Programs.html) check, to make sure the compiler is found.

Comment: Follow-up on my implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171949/implement-a-check-for-a-cxx-compilers-presence